# Configuring Mysql DataSource with IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, websphere

I have a spring mvc application which i am deploying on IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile, the application is supposed to access a mysql database server that is hosted locally. I have added the datasource configuration as follows in the sever.xml file

```
 <dataSource id="springdb" jndiName="jdbc/springdb">
  <jdbcDriver javax.sql.XADataSource="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" libraryRef="mysqlJDBCLib"/>
  <properties databaseName="spring_db" password="**********" portNumber="3306" serverName="localhost" user="root"/>
</dataSource>

<library id="mysqlJDBCLib">
  <fileset dir="/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty_16.0.0.4/usr/shared/resources/mysql" includes="mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar"/>
</library>
```

I am getting the following stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: DSRA4000E: A valid JDBC driver implementation class was not found for the jdbcDriver dataSource[springdb]/jdbcDriver[default-0] using the library mysqlJDBCLib. [/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty_16.0.0.4/usr/shared/resources/mysql/mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar]
at com.ibm.ws.resource.internal.ResourceFactoryTrackerData$1.getService(ResourceFactoryTrackerData.java:123)
... 77 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: DSRA4000E: A valid JDBC driver implementation class was not found for the jdbcDriver dataSource[springdb]/jdbcDriver[default-0] using the library mysqlJDBCLib. [/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty_16.0.0.4/usr/shared/resources/mysql/mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar]
at com.ibm.ws.jdbc.internal.JDBCDriverService.classNotFound(JDBCDriverService.java:196)
... 77 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:499)
... 77 more
```

I have tried the following

1. Replacing com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver with com.mysql.jdbc.Driver and string got the same error
2. Replacing javax.sql.XADataSource with javax.sql.DataSource and still got the same error
3. Replacing javax.sql.XADataSource with javax.sql.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource, same error
4. Switching out the mysql connector jar from mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar to mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar, still same error (both the jars are there in the specified file path)

Comment: I'd suggest you to leave only one of the libs because having both of them might lead to problems with classpath. Make sure the class that is pointed via `ClassNotFoundException` is really inside the jar (you can even unzip the jar and check). Have you tried the combination with `javax.sql.DataSource="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"`?

Comment: Yes i have removed one of the jars and used javax.sql.DataSource="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver". I have also unzipped the  jar and have made sure that the driver class is there

Comment: Does it still look for `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` when you use `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`?

Comment: Yes its still looking com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Background info about datasource config:**

For all datasources (except for `id="DefaultDataSource"`) the type of DataSource is selected in the following priority:

1. Use the `type` class configured on the `<dataSource>` element, if configured
2. javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource **This option is active in your case**
3. javax.sql.DataSource
4. javax.sql.XADataSource

(According to [Configuring relational database connectivity in Liberty](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html))

If no class is defined for a type, then the next lowest priority will be checked.

By default, Liberty will scan for use the following priority for locating data source implementation class names:

1. Use the corresponding value configured on the `<jdbcDriver>` element
2. Use the default classes for a `<properties.DRIVER_TYPE>` element. Note that only some JDBC drivers have their own element types.  For JDBC drivers that do not have their own properties element (such as MySQL) use the generic `<properties>` element
3. Based on the JDBC driver jar name, Liberty will try to guess the implementation class name.  **This option is active in your case**

---

**Reason why your configuration is not working**
You've configured your `<jdbcDriver>` element to say "Use this specific class for XADataSource's", however, the `<dataSource>` element you've configured is not attempting to create an `XADataSource`.  Using the priority order mentioned above, it will first try to create a `ConnectionPoolDataSource` (which Liberty has internally mapped to `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource`.

**To fix the problem:**

1. Specify `<dataSource .. type="javax.sql.XADataSource">` in your configuration so that Liberty will try to create an `XADataSource` instead of a `ConnectionPoolDataSource`.  Then when it tries to create the `XADataSource` it will look at the class name you've configured on the `<jdbcDriver>` element.
2. Specify MySQL's XADataSource class name for the `javax.sql.XADataSource` property (which is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource`) instead of their java.sql.Driver implementation class name.

So your final configuration would look like this:

```
<dataSource id="springdb" jndiName="jdbc/springdb" type="javax.sql.XADataSource">
  <jdbcDriver javax.sql.XADataSource="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource" libraryRef="mysqlJDBCLib"/>
  <properties databaseName="spring_db" password="**********" portNumber="3306" serverName="localhost" user="root"/>
</dataSource>

<library id="mysqlJDBCLib">
  <fileset dir="/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty_16.0.0.4/usr/shared/resources/mysql" includes="mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar"/>
</library>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specify the `type` attribute in the `dataSource` config element, Liberty will try to infer the datasource class to load based on the driver jar filename.  In your example, it is incorrectly inferring implementation class names based on a previous mySQL driver.  It appears that mySQL has changed the package names of their implementations for DataSource, ConnectionPoolDataSource and XADataSource.  I'll open an git issue for this.  In the meantime, you can simply specify the type of datasource to create using the `type` attribute of the `dataSource` config element and then update your `jdbcDriver` config element with `javax.sql.DataSource="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource"` to point to the proper mysql driver class.  If instead you need a conn pool or XA datasource instead, just update the `type` attribute of `dataSource` to identify the type and update `jdbcDriver` with the driver class impl.

Comment: I have realised that if i specify ```<dataSource .. type="javax.sql.XADataSource"> ```in my configuration Liberty will try to create an XADataSource instead of a ConnectionPoolDataSource. I dont even need to change the file name. Thanks for the correct class name.